# How to write a function to multiply large decimal numbers given as string

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, multiplication

```
   private fun sameTypeConvert() {
        val arr = units[fromType]!!.second
        if(fromIndex > toIndex) arr.reverse()
        while(fromIndex != toIndex){
            //Convert
            if(fromIndex < toIndex){
                num = (num.toDouble() * arr[toIndex - 1]).toString()
                toIndex--
            }
            else{
                num = (num.toDouble() / arr[fromIndex - 1]).toString()
                fromIndex--
            }
        }
```

Heres the github link for my project https://github.com/DeathsDoor/Units_of_Measurement_Conversions

It works in general but i want it to multiple huge DECIMAL numbers and I've not  been able to find the and on the net

Comment: If you want HUGE DECIMALs you must try to .toBigDecimal

Comment: Yeah but they can be inaccurate and I want to be able to do ridiculously huge numbers